# windows service recursive infinite loop with delayed execution for synchronous task

Tags: c#, recursion, windows-services, .net-4.5, delayed-execution

I am building a `Windows Service` to read records from a table, pass record data to a `WCF Service`, wait for its response and update the same record in the database depending on the response from the `WCF Service`. This process will continue for all the records and once all the records are processed, I need to delay further execution of code for `n` number of minutes. After the `n` minutes has elapsed, I need to call the same code to read records from the table again and process them and once all the records are processed, delay execution again for `n` number of minutes. This need to happen infinitely and the most important point is that all the executions should happen `synchronously` including the delayed execution, I want to completely avoid using `Threading` or `async/await` or any other asynchronous programming techniques.

After searching for while, I have learned that with `.NET Framework 4.5`, the recommended way is using `Task.Delay()` method without using `asycn/await` keywords to add a delay synchronously. So I have created a simple console application having a `recursive` method with an infinite loop:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RecursiveMethod();
        }

        public static void RecursiveMethod()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                DoWork();
                Console.WriteLine("Task delayed...");
                Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Calling method again recursively...");
                RecursiveMethod();
            }
        }

        public static void DoWork()
        {
            //Do some work
            Console.WriteLine("Work Completed.");
        }
    }
```

The above code seems to be working fine but I faced big issues when implementing `System.Timers.Timer` in another windows service, after running properly for two days, the `Timer` completely stopped working without throwing any exception, so no error was logged which is very frustrating.

I want to avoid such situations, so what is best way to implement `Task.Delay()` for simple synchronous code? The delay will be set to `2` hours so I want to also handle situations where the `Task.Delay()` will get garbage collected or removed from memory or stops working on its own (without throwing any exception) and restart the whole process again.

Comment: That will produce a stack overflow (after some time).

Comment: @SirRufo any other alternative to what I am trying to acheive?

Comment: Yes, read some tutorials about recursion to get a clou why you should not use it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Thread.Sleep(3000). Not sure why you want to avoid that. Your code is sync, so you shouldn't be using Task.

Also, Task.Delay uses a Timer. So not sure if that's going to solve your problem.

I'd try and figure out why the Timer object stopped working. That doesn't sound right.

Was your timer callback wrapped with a try catch?

Comment: yes it was wrapped in a try catch and all errors are logged to database...on to my question, any other alternative to `Thread.Sleep()` for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, `Task.Delay` is not appropriate here, since your code is not asynchronous. Also, you already have an infinite loop (`while (true)`), so there is no need for recursion:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    while (true)
    {
      DoWork();
      Console.WriteLine("Task delayed...");
      Task.Sleep(3000);
    }
  }

  public static void DoWork()
  {
    //Do some work
    Console.WriteLine("Work Completed.");
  }
}
```